# Asus laptop weird restart

Tags: laptop, reboot

Laptop Model :-X540YA-XO760T Win 10
What it does :- Suddenly hangs and restarts
alternate time it wont able to find wifi need again restart

What I tried:

1. Finding error through event viewer logs, no avail
2. checking cpu ,hdd etc temperature,atatched are stats, nothing found
3. installing new windows 10 ,no avail
4. scandisk,nothing found

No BSOD

Comment: You said you did a fresh install of Windows and still weird restart. So now use the ASUS Driver Update Support App and update BIOS, Chipset, and all other drivers. Do a final restart and test.

Comment: tried with driver update ,will check with bios